# Why I cannot use an object's prototype in JavaScript "isPrototypeOf"?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, instance

Does ES say that prototype is a property of all objects? Is yes, both "constructor function" and "object instance" are all function/object, then they should all have "prototype" property.

But when I tried:

```
var Person=function(){
    this.name='abc';
    this.age=30;
};
var o1=new Person();
var o2=new Person();                    
console.log(o2.prototype.isPrototypeOf(o1));
```

The console prints an exception saying:

```
console.log(o2.prototype.isPrototypeOf(o1));
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isPrototypeOf' of undefined
```

What is that error? I know that

```
console.log(Person.prototype.isPrototypeOf(o1));
```

works. But why "Person" has prototype with isPrototypeOf method, while o2 failed to have such property/method?

Then I tried this:

```
console.log(o2.prototype.prototype.isPrototypeOf);
```

It also fails, saying

```
console.log(o2.prototype.prototype.isPrototypeOf);
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

This is even more weird: if o2's prototype is "Person", then I expect

```
Person.prototype == o2.prototype.prototype
```

But why does it still fail?

Comment: _Instances_ generally don’t have `prototype`s. Only the constructor functions have one. You can try `Object.getPrototypeOf(o1)`. It’s the same with `Array.prototype` vs. `[].prototype`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
var Person=function(){
    this.name='abc';
    this.age=30;
};
var o1=new Person();
var o2=new Person(); 
o1.prototype = Person.prototype;
o2.prototype = Person.prototype;
console.log(o2.prototype.isPrototypeOf(o1));
```

Comment: Thanks, but question is, as long as "o1" is created by "Person()", isn't it automatic that the prototype of o1 is "Person.prototype"? Why need an extra prototype assignment?

Comment: Ah, because prototype is not available on the instances, but only on the constructor functions.